# Send and receive data by tcp socket in one thread

Tags: c++, sockets, events, pthreads

I have an applications with 2 threads. The first thread (main-thread) and the second thread (tcp-client-thread). The `main-thread` generates some messages and puts their in queue for `tcp-client-thread`. `tcp-client-thread` has to send those messages to server. But, `tcp-client-thread` also has to receive some messages from server.

How can I do that? `recv` stops current thread. Set up timeout for`recv`? Then after `recv` timeout check queue (from `main-thread`) and if there is messages send their is no any messages start `recv` again?

Answer (score 1):

You can do your I/O in one non-spinning/non-delayed thread but it's much more complex then just simply creating another thread as suggested in another answer.  In short, you'll have to modify your code to handle waiting for multiple event types simultaneously, i.e. an event on the socket OR on a condition signalling data to send, for example.  On Windows, you'd use something like WSAEventSelect + WaitForMultipleObjects instead of select, and on Linux you'd use something like eventfd with select.  Note that when handling the socket, if it's blocking, you'd want to check for readability before issuing a recv and check for writeability before issuing a send so you don't block on one or the other.  Like I said though, easier to just create a send thread...

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need is non-blocking/asynchronous I/O.
You should read some theory before trying to forge any code.
This article, for example:
http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use 2 threads, you might want to extend to 3 threads.  Let the send and receive functions be on separate threads.

The *send* thread is sleeping until the main thread gives it data.  Specifically, a function in the `send` software unit places data into the queue, then signals the thread to wake up.  The thread wakes up and sends data until the queue is empty, then it goes back to sleep.

Conversely, the *receive* thread sleeps until it receives data.  It appends data to another queue, notifies the *main* thread that data was received and goes back to sleep.

**Edit 1: One Thread**
Per your title, if you want to perform the I/O in one thread, you will need to have a polling loop (you can have limited waiting, but not advised).

```
Loop:  
  if (data received) then place data into input queue.
  if (data in input queue) process some data (use small chunks).
  if (data in output queue) send some data.
end-loop.
```

The idea is to keep the blocks of data small to prevent missing of incoming data.  The data can be processed and output when there is no data (and with multiple iterations).  This will resolve most synchronization issues.